# Enter items/elements to a blank list by taking user input

Tags: python, list, append

I have written a code and it's working fine, just one problem that iam working with append() and i know that append adds element in the end of the list.
I want the list not to start from a blank element.

```
`#this function adds append items to list by taking input from the user
add_item_to_list= input("Enter item to add to list :")
my_list.append(add_item_to_list)
my_list=[" "]
another_item=input("add another item y/n ?")
while another_item=="y" :
  add_item_to_list= input("Enter item to add to list :")
  another_item=input("add another item y/n ?")
  my_list.append(add_item_to_list)
print(my_list)`
```

Comment: Your code sample would throw a `NameError`; you might want to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding on initialization `my_list=[" "]` a `blank` element (as you are saying).
Just initialize it without it:

`my_list = []`

`my_list` must be initalized before `my_list.append(add_item_to_list)`

Comment: *And* put that line *before* the first `my_list.append(...)` line.

Comment: that's correct @9769953